find and cp command don't work in my script but they work in my terminal
In my current directory, I have a list  (list.txt) file like this
Container ID
W1412886
W1402878
W1402821
W1402789
W1402792
...

I also have folders that contains files whose file name start with the values shown in the previous list.
I also have a script with which I want to loop over each element of my list and copy the found files into a directory called FINAL. This script is pretty simple but for a reason I don't know is not working
#!/bin/bash

# Path to your file containing container IDs
container_file="list.txt"
# Destination folder
destination_folder="FINAL"

# Create destination folder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$destination_folder"

# Skip the header and process each container ID in the file
tail -n +2 "$container_file" | while IFS= read -r container_id || [[ -n "$container_id" ]]; do
    # Check if the line is not empty
    if [[ -n "$container_id" ]]; then
        echo "Processing Container ID: $container_id"  # Debugging line
        # Find files that start with the container ID and copy them to the FINAL folder
        find . -type f -name ${container_id}* -exec cp {} "$destination_folder" \;
    fi
done

I get the Container ID from the echo but it cannot copy. Interestingly if I run the following command, this works
 find . -type f -name W1412886* -exec cp {} FINAL \;

Do you have any idea why it is working in a single command but the loop (that seems to work) is not copying? I am using git bash

In your statement try wrapping container_id within quotes similar to destination_folder
"${container_id}*"

I have tried all possible combinations of wrapping and unwrapping ${container_id} and "$destination_folder" and nothing work

what do you mean by it cannot copy? do you receive an error message? does it silently do nothing? something else? please update the question with this additional detail

I mean it not doing anything. No error, nothing happens.

See How can I debug a Bash script? and the Debugging section of BashGuide/Practices - Greg's Wiki.

One possible cause of the problem is that your list.txt file has Windows (CR-LF) line termination.  See the "Before asking about problematic code" section of the Stack Overflow 'bash' Info page.  Also see Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?.

Try adding -print to the find command so you'll see if it's matching any files.

bash -x script to see what's happening

A reworked (minor changes,comments removed) of your script, using a 'dos' formatted list.txt file.
As others mentioned, list.txt is probably CRLF (aka windows aka dos formatted records) is the root issue, also added -print to 'find....', cater for dos formatted records - works without change on standard 'unix' text files
$ ls -l W*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 0 Nov  3 21:49 W1402789.0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 0 Nov  3 21:49 W1402789.1
---------- 1 tester tester 0 Nov  3 22:14 W1402792
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 0 Nov  3 21:49 W1402878.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 0 Nov  3 21:49 W1402878.2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 0 Nov  3 21:49 W1402878.3

$ file list.txt
list.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

$ cat list.txt
Container ID
W1412886
W1402878

W1402821
W1402789
W1402792

$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

container_file="list.txt"
destination_folder="FINAL"

mkdir -p "$destination_folder"

while IFS= read -r container_id
do
    if [[ -n "$container_id" ]]; then
        echo "Processing Container ID: $container_id"
        find . -type f -name "${container_id}*" -print -exec cp -f {} "$destination_folder" \;
    fi
done <<< $(tail -n +2 "$container_file" | tr -d '\r') # cater for 'dos' formatted lines

$ ./script.sh
Processing Container ID: W1412886
Processing Container ID: W1402878
./W1402878.2
./W1402878.1
./W1402878.3
Processing Container ID: W1402821
Processing Container ID: W1402789
./W1402789.0
./W1402789.1
Processing Container ID: W1402792
./W1402792
cp: cannot open './W1402792' for reading: Permission denied

$ ls FINAL/
W1402789.0  W1402789.1  W1402878.1  W1402878.2  W1402878.3

hope this helps, or let the community know if you've resolved your issue.
